# Slaughtering during the nine days nowadays

Tags: halacha, nine-days, slaughter-shochet-shecht

[*Shulchan Aruch*, *Orach Chayim* 551:9](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14166&pgnum=53):

> Some have the custom not to eat meat… during the week [of 9 *Av*, until after 9 *Av*]; some add from *rosh chodesh* until the fast; some add from 17 *Tamuz*.

*Rama* holds of the middle view. He adds:

> We hide the slaughtering knife from *rosh chodesh*, since we don't slaughter (except for a *mitzva*, as for a sick person, the sabbath, a *mila*, or the like).

Nowadays, obviously, we don't need to slaughter animals right before eating them. Moreover, many non-Jews buy kosher meat. The above-implied reason for not slaughtering during the nine days is pretty much gone.

- What is the current common practice? Are kosher slaughterhouses open during the nine days? during the week of 9 *Av*?
- Are there any *pos'kim* that explicitly permit or ban slaughtering at this time of year in light of modern technology, infrastructure, and/or demand?

Answer (score 7):

[The Aruch HaShulchan in OH 551:25](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9102&pgnum=235) writes, after quoting the Ramo in the question:

ומובן ממילא דבעיר גדולה שיש בה תמיד כמה חולאים וכמה יולדות, והרבה חלושי הבריאות – לא שייך להצניע הסכין

"And it is understood automatically that in a big city where there always many sick people and many women who have given birth and many weak people -- it is not relevant to hide the knife"

Comment: An excellent source! I wonder if modern factories have adopted this psak?